# Is it possible to thread a subclass within a class?

Tags: python, multithreading, parent-child, irc, subclass

This is for a moderation bot for C&C Renegade, in case anyone wants some background.

I have a class which will act as a parent to a load of subclasses that provide IRC connections, connections to the gamelog (UDP socket), etc, and I want to know if it is possible to split some of these subclasses (notably the two socket connections [IRC, gamelog]) into their own threads using the threading module.

If anyone has any suggestions, even if it's just saying it can't be done, I'd appreciate the input.

Tom

Edit: I have experience with working with threaded applications, so I'm not a complete noob, honest.

Comment: Don't see why not.  A threaded subsystem is not unusual.  The fun bit is getting the comms into and out of the subclasses right, ie. flexible enough for various linksk and protocols underneath while providing a common interface via. the overridden methods and callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

It is feasible, take a look at:

[multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html)

Besides the simple process forking, it also provides memory sharing - which is likely to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to run your app with [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) coroutines. Those are much more light-weight than threads and processes. The library has been created based on green threads   execution units. [Here](http://codescience.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/non-blocking-io-node-js-and-pythons-eventlet/) you can find a good comparison and benchmark of the execution models of Eventlet (A python library that provides a synchronous interface to do asynchronous I/O operations which uses  green threads to achieve cooperative sockets) and node.js.